# A recommended way to use Spring application context within Eclipse RCP project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse-rcp

what would be a recommended way to work with Spring application context within Eclipse RCP project.

I have a Swing based application that is wired together by Spring and its configurations. What would be the best strategy for these two, without too many conflicts between them (I'm just beginning with Eclipse RCP, and I am mostly worried about how similarly eclipse plugin.xml looks in comparison with xxx-context.xml.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to use Spring in Eclipse RCP project is to use it with Spring Dynamic Modules. I define beans in diffrent contexts over the plugins and export some of them as osgi services to allow beans from other plugins use them in dependency injection. Also I implemented some kind of ServiceAccessor (singleton wrapper over osgi service accessor) that displays "waiting services to be registered" dialog to user until all necessary services will be registered.